# Accessing Variables Of Sub-objects/models from within a backbone view template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-views

Given a JSON response from my server as follows:

```
{
"products" : [
    {
        "Product" : {
            "id" : "122",
            "name" : "product X",
            "price" : "19.99",
        },
        "Picture" : [
            {
                "product_id" : "122",
                "id" : "145",
            },
            {
                "product_id" : "122",
                "id" : "146",
            },
            {
                "product_id" : "122",
                "id" : "147",
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I will create a backbone model that will be passed to a backbone View.  In my View's template I can access the product's name with:

```
 <%= Product.name %>
```

and all works as expected.  But lets say I want to get the id of the first Picture.  I tried:

```
<%= Picture.0.id %>
```

But I get the following error in my console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

So in a nutshell how do I access the properties of the various pictures associated with my product from the product template.  I am using underscore templates if that matters.

Comment: Note that, in general, you should use `<%- %>` instead of `<%= %>` as it properly escapes values and protects against XSS attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal javascript array indexer syntax `[index]` will do the trick:

```
<%= Picture[0].id %>
```

**Edit**: Underscore accepts any old javascript inside the `<% %>` tags, so if you want to check whether an array is empty, you can do so using the standard `_.isEmpty` method:

```
<% if(!_.isEmpty(Picture)) { %>
   <%= Picture[0].id %>
<% } else { %>
   No picture
<% } %>
```

Or any other javascript construct you prefer. [See docs](http://underscorejs.org/#template) for more info.

Comment: I tested this via the console and it works as expected.  However from with an underscore template Its still a no go. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: Can you show how you're passing the model to the view and the template?

Comment: @NeilHolcomb, the template expression does work, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Pz3DY/1/ .There is something else wrong with your rendering code / data - maybe a product with an empty `Picture` array?

Comment: DOH! that was it.  The empty Picture array was killing the scripts and nothing rendered.  Now for the shortcut question, in an underscore template can we test for an empty array?

Comment: @fencliff I don't have enough reputation to vote you up, so I'll say thanks here... you saved me hours of facepalming this evening.

Comment: @NeilHolcomb, glad to have helped.. That's what we're here for.. that and killing time because of chronic insomnia.